# NoScript: How do I block a subdomain but allow the parent domain?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, noscript

I want to allow scripts from DomainIVisitOften.com, but block ads.DomainIVisitOften.com. Is there a way to do that with NoScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NoScript's ABE module for fine tuning: http://noscript.net/faq#qa8_10

Also, you can setup the Appearance options to show subdomains, and mark that one as untrusted.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest [Adblock for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/) if you just want to block ads ? I don't see any options myself to block specific subdomains from noscript.